# R in Power BI: Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values

Tags: r, powerbi

**Using R visualization in Power BI**

**Error:**

```
Stack Trace:
Microsoft.PowerBI.ExploreServiceCommon.ScriptHandlerException: R script error.
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
Calls: plot -> plot.default -> localWindow -> plot.window
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Execution halted
 ---> Microsoft.PowerBI.Radio.RScriptRuntimeException: R script error.
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
Calls: plot -> plot.default -> localWindow -> plot.window
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Execution halted
```

I'm getting the above error only when I try to subset my data.

From reading other similar questions I have checked my data types and they were Integer and Double respectively.

I have also checked for NA values in the data using `any(is.na(dataset))` and it showed that there are no NA values.

When I put in `xlim` and `ylim` values, my plot becomes blank.

**Code:**

```
dataset <- dataset[dataset$Column1=="T1",] #Subset of data I want. All rows where Column1 is equal to T1.

x <- as.numeric(dataset$`Height`) # Integer
y <- as.numeric(dataset$`Pct Pop`)  # Double
plot(x, y,
xlim = c(0, 45000),
ylim = c(0, 1.5)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this error by adding the filter I wanted using the power bi filtering method instead of trying to create a subset of my data like you normally would in R. To accomplish this, click on your chart and at the bottom right you will see a section called "Filters" where you can add your columns and constraints.

Comment: This works like charm! It seems we don't have to perform filtering using Rscript. Instead use Power Bi filters to filter and eventually import the data.